# find custom message with 500 error inside of iron-ajax error response

Tags: polymer

I'm making about member sign-up process.

I'm using iron-ajax for requesting query.

On the serverside, I handle this request.
I'm checking the user has UNIQUE email ID.
If not, I send 500 error status with error message.

[image]

When I try this process by using Postman, It works fine, I can see 500 status with error message.

[image]

But I try this using Polymer's iron-ajax, "on-error" function invoked but 
there I can't find any error message field.

```
<iron-ajax id="joinAjax"
     on-response="_onJoinResponse"
     on-error="_onJoinError"></iron-ajax>

_onJoinError: function (e) {
        console.log(e.detail.response); // **undefined**
}
```

How can I determine what specific error occured with 500 status?
What I want is containig custom error code in message, so that I can determine errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you better return  the status code  as 400, if you submit some invalid data.

By the way, in iron-ajax, you can not get return data if u return 500 status code